# logstash - collecting information about ip connected to server

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I am using ELK to visualize the information of ip address of all the clients(machines connected via putty) machines connected to my server.
I am using 'last' command to get list of ip address of all the machines connected to my server.

The output of last command is as below

root     pts/0        32.97.110.56     Mon Oct  5 16:44- 17:33 (19:03)

root     pts/0        32.97.110.56     Mon Oct  5 18:06 - 18:19  (00:12)

When I am pushing this information on kibana, using logstash and elastic search I can see the message as below.

message: root pts/0 32.97.110.56 Mon Oct 5 16:44 - 17:33

I want to split the 'message' by space so that I can have different fields for each in kibana.
Please suggest me how I can do that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [`grok`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) filter can be used to parse the message into more useful structure for querying.

`grok` patterns are regular expressions but also include a [library of common patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/tree/master/patterns) that can be used rather than writing your own expression from scratch. A useful pattern for this type of simple parsing is `NOTSPACE` which matches any non-whitespace characters. Other patterns such as `IP` can also be useful to ensure that the data selected is actually what you expected.

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => {
      "message" => "^%{NOTSPACE:user} %{NOTSPACE:tty} %{IP:ip}"
    }
    named_captures_only => true
  }
}
```